# How to tell Webdriver not to switch window focus when running tests?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, capybara

When I run Webdriver tests, it automatically changes window focus to browser window when doing operation like file uploads and others.

I don't want such behavior as I may work in other windows at the moment.

Can I prohibit it? How?

Comment: My first thought is: It's a feature and you might consider switching to `HTMLUnitDriver` ... but I will have second thought about it and post answer if I come up with something better...

Comment: You should always run your Selenium tests on a separate device anyway.

Comment: @MarthynOlthof but I debug them on my device, not separate

Comment: I think this is mostly OS related than to a behaviour from Selenium tbh.

Comment: I would be highly surprised if you could do much about this. Sounds way outside Selenium's scope.